# Not getting vertical scroolbar to custom datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

Hi all I am trying to apply vertical scrollbar to custom data table in LWC its not coming. Can anyone suggest what should be tried My sample code I pasted below.

```
 <template>
        <lightning-card title="Top 10 Processes invoking Emails" icon-name="utility:chart">
            <div style="height: 272px; overflow-y:auto;">
        
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_col-bordered"
            aria-label="Example table of Opportunities with vertical borders">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Process Name">Process Name</div>
                    </th>
                    <th class="" scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="API Calls">API Calls</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <template for:each={inputData} for:item="data" for:index="index">
                    <tr key={data.Id}>
                        <td data-label="Process Name">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={data.name}>{data.name}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="API Calls">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={data.value}>{data.value}</div>
                        </td>
    
                    </tr>
                </template>
    
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ROPTTopTenProcessEmail extends LightningElement {

    inputData =[{name:'Sync Leads data',value:1200},{name:'Process Leads data',value:800},
    {name:'Invoking onboarding emails',value:750},{name:'Process Customer data',value:700},
    {name:'Opportunity resell process',value:200},{name:'Sync Accounts data',value:200},
    {name:'Generate Lead from Marketing tool',value:200},{name:'Sync documents from external system',value:200},
    {name:'Sync Partners data',value:200},{name:'Process Partner data',value:200},];
    


}
```

Comment: I pasted your code in as-is, and I'm seeing the scrollbar in Chrome. See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/22peo.png

Comment: Yes Thank you. Its working fine. It was a refresh issue I had to do a hard refresh.